# Generate control C# code from NIB's and insert into MonoTouch's designer.cs files - Visual Studio style

Tags: c#, xcode, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I've begun using MonoTouch 5.x. I feel like I'm fighting NIB's to use inheritance.

I want to use inheritance. I want to use a designer to make my views. I want it all.

So I've been searching for a tool that generates xxx.designer.cs files like VS does it: inserting the controls in code on the fly when designing using IB. Reducing NIB's to a design-time feature.

As far as I can tell, this is the cleanest approach with the best performance that allows me to go full C#, "visual inheritance", etc.

Does anyone know of such an initiative? In any form or shape?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Visual Studio you are able to write an implementation of IVsSingleFileGenerator.
Which is then used as custom tool to generate files at design time.

Maybe there is a similar feature in monodevelop.